# React native build error for react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have added react-native-camera to my application. But I am getting this error while running `npm run android` command.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I have made all the required changes to build.gradle and settings.gradle. I am running react-native 0.64.0 version and node 16.4.2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cory Cunningham mentioned, it was because of async storage. So I installed the following version of @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.5",
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error has more to do with the async storage library it seems, as indicated on the error. So I would check that implementation first.

Second, I would advise against using `react-native-camera` since it has been [deprecated](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera) for a while now. Most people seem to have moved to [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) or [react-native-camera-kit](https://github.com/teslamotors/react-native-camera-kit) (which I use and would suggest).

Comment: I have tried uninstalling react-native-camera and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's because of your implementation of your async storage package. As I said in my answer before, the error seems to point to that.
`Could not resolve project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage`

Comment: I have downgraded my JDK to version 8 and got this working. Thanks for your help.